# Legend not showing icons in Maps Javascript API

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, icons, legend

I'm trying to use a legend with scaled size icons, but the legend isn't loaded correctly.

I'm working on the following code:

```
var icons = {
    3: {
       name: '-39,7309 a -39,3293',
       icon: {
           url: 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/red-dot.png',
           scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(5, 8)
       }
    },
    2: {
       name: '-39,3293 a -38,9277',
       icon: {
           url: 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/red-dot.png',
           scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(10, 17)
       }
    }
};
var legend = document.getElementById('legend');
for (var key in icons) {
    var type = icons[key];
    var name = type.name;
    var icon = type.icon;
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + icon + '">' + name;
    legend.appendChild(div);
};
```

The pin is displayed like a X:
[image]

What's wrong?

Comment: I've already know how to make legend display icons: div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + icon.url + '">' + name;. But I can't make the pins to be with different sizes when using scaledSize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML `<img>` tags need a URL.  You are giving it a Google Maps Icon object.

(I get an error in the javascript console: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)   [object%20Object]`)

You have to give it `icon.url`, any scaling needs to be done in the HTML/CSS.  The `<img>` tag has height and width attributes, you can use those to scale the image based off the values in the `scaledSize` property:

```
var icons = {
  3: {
    name: '-39,7309 a -39,3293',
    icon: {
      url: 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/red-dot.png',
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(5, 8)
    }
  },
  2: {
    name: '-39,3293 a -38,9277',
    icon: {
      url: 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/red-dot.png',
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(10, 17)
    }
  }
};
var legend = document.getElementById('legend');
for (var key in icons) {
  var type = icons[key];
  var name = type.name;
  var icon = type.icon;
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + icon.url + '" height="' + icon.scaledSize.height + '" width="' + icon.scaledSize.width + '">' + name;
  legend.appendChild(div);
};
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/vejf7f5L/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var icons = {
    3: {
      name: '-39,7309 a -39,3293',
      icon: {
        url: 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/red-dot.png',
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(5, 8)
      }
    },
    2: {
      name: '-39,3293 a -38,9277',
      icon: {
        url: 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/red-dot.png',
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(10, 17)
      }
    }
  };
  var legend = document.getElementById('legend');
  for (var key in icons) {
    var type = icons[key];
    var name = type.name;
    var icon = type.icon;
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + icon.url + '" height="' + icon.scaledSize.height + '" width="' + icon.scaledSize.width + '">' + name;
    legend.appendChild(div);
  };
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="legend"></div>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, geocodezip. I spent hours looking for a solution.